# After adding span tag in contenteditable cursor move to end in IOS safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a feature where users can click on the tag and the same has been added to `contenteditable` div. this works fine but when I do it back and forth the cursor moves the end of the div.

This is when user adds variable first time and cursor seems fine.

[image]

This is when user remove and add tag again

[image]

The tag has been added by the following code and this issue is happing in ios safari only.

```
insertTextAtCursor = (text, paste = false) => {
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    // Make sure we're focused on the compose element
    this.compose.focus(); // contenteditable div ref

    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
      const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();
      if (paste) {
        range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(text));
        range.selectNode(document.createTextNode(text));
      } else {
        range.insertNode(text);
        range.selectNode(text);
      }
      // calling deleteContents and replacing with HTML leaves behind an empty node, so here we clean discard it.
      const newRange = range.cloneRange();
      range.setEndBefore(text);
      newRange.setStartAfter(text);
      newRange.setEndAfter(text);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(newRange);
    }
  }
```

**Edit**
The cursor becomes too big after adding `display: inline-block` property.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="variable-message-input-message-fb39fc57-7909-47e2-9de8-042e70eee3ad" class="variable-message__compose" contenteditable="true" name="message" placeholder="" style="
/* display: inline-block; */"><span spellcheck="false" contenteditable="false" id="span-First Name" class="variable-message__variable"><i>{</i><div>First</div><b>_</b><div>Name</div><i>}</i><span class="variable-message__close"></span></span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
background-color: #fcfcfc;
border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
border-top-left-radius: .2rem;
border-top-right-radius: .2rem;
color: #404040;
min-height: 4rem;
padding: 1rem 1.2rem;
```

Comment: Share HTML Code Please...

Answer (score 0):

Try add this below css

```
[contenteditable] {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: this work but the cursor becomes too big. I have uploaded screenshot question

Comment: can you share your css

Comment: I have added HTML / CSS to my question